# TCL create a list

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

I'm an absolute beginner and can't quite wrap my head around Tcl. I need some help with something that I think is very basic. Any help would be appreciated. I have a text file that I want to import into Tcl. I'll give you the syntax of the file and my desired way to store it:

text FILE to import into Tcl:

```
Singles 'pink granny fuji'
Singles2 'A B C D E'
Couples 'bread butter honey lemon cinnamon sugar'
Couples2 'A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2 D1 D2'
```

My desired format:

For lines 1 & 2:

```
Singles 
[pink granny fuji] ( 3 single elements)

Singles2
[A B C D E] (5 single elements)
```

For lines 3 & 4:

```
Couples
[bread butter
honey lemon 
cinnamon sugar] (3 x 2 array)

Couples2 
[A1 A2
B1 B2 
C1 C2
D1 D2] (4 x 2 array)
```

The import text file can in theory have any number of elements, but lines 3&4 will always be an even number of elements so that they are pairs, so I know a for each loop is needed to capture any number of elements. I know the code will also need to strip the apostrophes from the text file.

I'm just really struggling at the moment, really appreciate any help at all, thank you :)

Comment: Just need to know what you know. Do you know what a list is in tcl? Do you know about foreach? Are you familiar with regexp?

Comment: My first clarification question: How should the code decide whether to use the first or second output format? Is it because of the string `Single` at the front or the string `Couple` at the front or because of the numerical indices counting through the input data?

Comment: My second clarification question: What are the rules for the words inside the single quotes? Do they ever have “special” characters in them — including embedded spaces used as separators — or are they always simple alphanumerics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is solution. It works perfectly. I hope you are looking for similar solution.

```
   set handle [open "text_import" "r"]
   set content [read $handle]
   regsub -all {'} $content "" content
   #set content [split [read $handle] \n]
   set content [split $content \n]

   foreach ele $content {
       puts $ele
       if {[regexp -nocase -- "(\[^ \]+) +(.*)" $ele - key val]} {
           puts $key
           if {[regexp -nocase -- "single" $key]} {
               set val1 [split $val " "]
               set arr($key) $val1
           } elseif {[regexp -nocase -- "couple" $key]} {
               set biggerList [list]
               set val2 [split $val " "]
               for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $val2]} {incr i 2} {
                   set tempList [list [lindex $val2 $i] [lindex $val2 [expr $i + 1]]]
                   lappend biggerList $tempList
               }
               set arr($key) $biggerList
           }
       }
   }


   parray arr
```

~

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your code and the syntax helped me to write my code, in the end I used readFile, string match, range and trim to do it. I didn't even need a regexp as my input file was quite simple, but really great to see the example and I know for next time how to use regexp. Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Great that it has helped you. Do no forget to +1 it so that anyone looking for this kind of solution can see it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution. Instead of loading the textfile as data, we can load it as Tcl source if we make the right definitions.

```
proc Singles args {
    set str [string trim [join $args] ']
    puts "\[$str]"
}

proc Singles2 args {
    set str [string trim [join $args] ']
    puts "\[$str]"
}

proc Couples args {
    set list [split [string trim [join $args] ']]
    foreach {a b} $list {
        lappend list2 "$a $b"
    }
    set str [join $list2 \n]
    puts "\[$str]"
}

proc Couples2 args {
    set list [split [string trim [join $args] ']]
    foreach {a b} $list {
        lappend list2 "$a $b"
    }
    set str [join $list2 \n]
    puts "\[$str]"
}

source textfile.txt
```

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[source](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The idea definitely helped me, in the end I used readFile, string match, range and trim to do it. Thanks again :)